# Openpyxl in python making for loop to merge specific row from many excel files into one

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to make an python code that takes out a specific row from a excel sheet and copies into one. I want to do this with many files (about 1000 files). So I want a specific row in every excel document to get put in to a new row in the destination excel file. How do i modify my code to do this?

Here is what I have right now:

```
filename =str('c:\\user\\script\\results\\viktor\\ESS_result_DetectorE503B35_Sewage.xlsx')
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename) 
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0] 
 

filename1 ="c:\\user\\script\\results\\viktor\\ESS.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1) 
ws2 = wb2.active

mr = 2
mc = ws1.max_column

for i in filename:
   for j in range (1, mc + 1): 

       c = ws1.cell(row = 3, column = j) 

       ws2.cell(row = 3, column = j).value = c.value 
 

wb2.save(str(filename1))
```

Comment: This code cannot work. What is `for i in filename` supposed to do?

Comment: It works, well you can change out i to mr and get the same result where it takes out the third row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ur case, u shouldn't loop the string of `filename`  but list of `filenames`.

```
filenames = [ur filenames here]
source_xl_filename = r'xxxxxx'
source_wb = xl.load_workbook(source_xl_filename) 
ws1 = source_wb.worksheets[0]

def batch_save_xl(filename):
    wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename) 
    ws2 = wb2.active
    mr = 2
    mc = ws1.max_column
    for i in filename:
        for j in range (1, mc + 1): 
            c = ws1.cell(row = 3, column = j) 
            ws2.cell(row = 3, column = j).value = c.value 
    wb2.save(str(filename1))

for filename in filenames:
    batch_save_xl(filename)
```

Comment: That still won't work. And can you please spell out pronouns.